# Running AWS Command Line Interface using Jenkins: command not found?

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, jenkins, command-line-interface, pip

Here is my infrastructure:

- **M1** is Jenkins master, running OS X (Mountain Lion)
- **M2** is Jenkins slave, running OS X (Mountain Lion)
- **J** is a Jenkins job, running on **M2**

On **M2**, I have installed [AWC CLI using pip](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html#install-with-pip), and run `aws` command manually successfully.

I set up the **J** job to run that `aws` command. But when **J** runs, it fails and the error message is:

```
... aws: command not found
```

Do you have any idea this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not so tough though: I should have given the full path to `aws` tool. In my case, the correct command should be:

```
/usr/local/bin/aws <other sub-command and options>
```

This solves the problem. Hope this will save someone few hours struggling.

Comment: I caouldn't locate aws in my jenkins. So no command worked for me. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @PrabhuKhannaMahadevan your Jenkins server probably doesn't have the AWS CLI installed. You'll need to install it.

Comment: Facing similar issue when appended with /usr/local/bin it says No such file or directory

Comment: @Rizwan It looks like your awscli installation is not in /usr/local/bin. In this case you'll need to locate the binary first (by running the command "which aws", I guess? Or consult the installation documentation you followed).

Answer (score 2):

on your jenkins server 'sudo -i -u jenkins' install aws cli under the jenkins user.

Answer (score 1):

If the solution by Nguyen doesn't work try this path,
My Jenkins build [with EnvInject] was setup to install AWS in `/home/jenkins/.local/bin/aws`

Comment: Verified with which aws -> /home/jenkins/.local/bin/aws
added this in script part of jenkin job but giving error as No Such file or directory

Comment: @Rizwan What is the output when you run "/home/jenkins/.local/bin/aws --version" manually in your shell session?

Answer (score 1):

To provide a general working solution you could execute `which aws` which will provide the exact path of aws binary, or even: `$(which aws)` which is equivalent to executing `aws`